# What is the smallest molecule that can present as an antigen to the immune system in the context of allergies?

Tags: immunology, antigen, allergies

People often claim, in a colloquial sense, that they are "allergic to everything".

Is it possible to have a full-fledged IgE mediated allergic response to very small molecules?  I was always under the impression that the smallest antigen was a oligopeptide, but is it possible for someone to be allergic to something like isopropanol, glucose, or another small organic molecule?

How about allergies to metals, as I know those are fairly common, would they be mediated through a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At one of my previous companies that raised antibodies to proteins and post-translational modifications, we found that 6-8 amino acids was generally the smallest peptide length required for an epitope. Anything much smaller than that won't induce the cross-linking or conformational changes required for signal transduction and an allergic response. As WYSIWYG notes, allergies to small molecules/atoms are formed via [hapten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapten)-carrier interactions. These can be covalent, as in the nickel-transferrin example, or as a result of denaturation/chemical modification, as likely happens with people who are allergic to things like isopropanol or bleach.

I very much doubt that there can be such a thing as a glucose allergy, as it is so ubiquitous in the body that such antibodies/T-cells would be [negatively selected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_selection_%28immunology%29) long before they could do any damage.

Comment: Yes, the glucose example was a figment of my imagination, I just wondered if it was theoretically possible, but your point about negative selection is surely true.

Comment: @jonsca you are correct. However, plasma glucose can spontaneously react with the amine side chains of proteins and form **pro-inflammatory** [advanced glycation endproducts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_glycation_end-product).  Certain immune cells have receptors for AGEs.  So although AGE-drive inflammtion is not an adaptive (antigen driven) immune response, it is immune mediated.

Answer (score 14):

Small molecules do not have antigenic properties but they can elicit immune response by binding to a "carrier" protein. The small molecule is called a Hapten. An epitope forms at the protein-hapten binding interface.

[Nickel](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15767020)  acts like a hapten and elicits immune response by binding to proteins like transferrin, albumin etc.

Other metals also cause allergy in a similar way.